# Why my function is returning 11 instead of 5?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to solve a problem with leetcode label **Compliment of Base 10 Integer**. By theory, if you **Exclusive OR(XOR) One(1)** with any number you will get the compliment of that number. For example, if you XOR (111) With 5(101) you will get 2(010)

**Note: Assuming that the input is 10. It is returning 11 instead of 5**

[This is the link to the question that I am trying to solve](https://leetcode.com/problems/complement-of-base-10-integer/)

**This is what I wrote**

```
class Solution {
public int bitwiseComplement(int n) {
    return (n^1);
}
```

}

Comment: Show more examples, and I don't think your theory holds. For example, `111 XOR 001` does not return zero as the link wants

Comment: "*if you XOR ONE(1) With 5(101) you will get 2(010)*" - Nope. XORing `0b101` with `0b001` results in `0b100`, which is `4` in base10, as expected.

Comment: "By theory if you Exclusive OR(XOR) One(1) with any number you will get the compliment of that number." <- Where did you get that from? I never heard of that before and can't really think of any reason why it should be true.

Comment: XORing with 1 flips the lowest bit, nothing else.

Comment: We can of course flip all bits by XORing with `-1`, but this will flip **all** bits.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the 'XOR with 1' notion.  The value you need to XOR with to get the complement is a number of the same binary length consisting of ALL 1s.  So to get the complement of 1010 you would XOR with 1111 (i.e. 0101).

Comment: @Turing85  **This is what I am trying to say**.<br /> `101(5) ^ 111 = 010(2)`

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea maybe, but that's not what you wrote. And `0b111 != -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this trick. `~` operation switch `0 <-> 1`.

```java
int a = 0b010;
int b = ~a & 0b111; // 0x101
```

So the solution is pretty simple:

1. Find the highest `1` bit; it gives you the number of bits for the mask
2. User `~` to find a compliment number and limit it to the number of bits.

Comment: The point of such coding competitions is to solve them yourself. What is the point of dropping a complete solution then? Why not give essential hints why the given code is wrong, and how to *get* to working code?

Answer (score 0):

**Why 10 ^ 1 = 11** (and not 5)

10 in binary is `1010` and 1 in binary is  `0001`

now lets calculate 1010 ^ 0001

```
  1010
^ 0001
  ----
  1011
  ----
```

1011 in decimal is 11! (since 5 in binary is 0101)